# how to print the text values of Freebase Topic API in JQuery

Tags: jquery

how can I print the text Values of this Result. I tried this code but it failed

```
var topicid = "/m/02jttf";
$.getJSON(service_url +'?callback=?',function(response) {
     $.each(response.values, function(i, Values) {
          $('<div>', {text:values['text']}).appendTo(document.body);
    });
});
```

sample of the result

```
funcname({
 "id": "/m/02jttf",
 "property": {
  "/common/topic/article": {
   "valuetype": "compound",
   "values": [
    {
     "text": "Kano is a city in Nigeria and the capital of Kano State in Northern Nigeria. Its metropolitan...",
     "lang": "en",
     "id": "/m/02jttr",
     "creator": "/user/mwclikipedia_en",
     "timestamp": "2006-10-22T16:58:02.001Z",
     "property": {
      "/common/document/source_uri": {
       "valuetype": "uri",
       "values": [
        {
         "text": "hsaffffsd",
         "lang": "",
         "value": "sfffsfsfs",
         "creator": "/user/wikipedia_en",
         "timestamp": "2006-10-22T16:58:02.001Z"
        }
       ],
       "count": 1.0
      },
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(response.values, function(i, Values) {
          $('<div>', {text:values['text']}).appendTo(document.body);
    });
```

You have `Values` and you are printing `values['text']`,the `values` is not declared.

You should do it like this

```
$.each(response.property, function(_, prop) {
      $.each(prop.values, function(_, value) {
          $('<div />', { text : value.text }).appendTo('body');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need more iteration to access the inner `values` properties

```
var topicid = "/m/02jttf";
$.getJSON(service_url +'?callback=?',function(response) {
     $.each(response.property, function(_, prop) {
          $.each(prop.values, function(_, value) {
              $('<div />', { text : value.text }).appendTo('body');
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is true for accessing inner values, but in OP's case his code should work too.

Comment: How would that work, there is no `response.values`, it's `response.property["/common/topic/article"].values` ?

Comment: Sorry my bad,I overlooked.

Comment: @skmasq - now you just copied mine 8), and it doesn't work either !